# Linq to SQL 2016 Stored Procedure OFFSET FETCH NEXT incorrect return type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have an interesting issue that has kept me googling for a couple of days.

I am executing a stored store procedure that implements Offset Fetch Next for custom .net paging.

The entity framework can't seem to figure out the correct return type.  It thinks I am trying to return an int instead of a result set.  Therefore I can not use select.

sproc code:

```
  @param1 bit = null,
  @param2 bit = null,
  @pageNumber int = 1,
  @rowsPage int = 10

 SELECT        id, name
 FROM          table
 WHERE
        (@param1 IS NULL OR (param1 = @param1 )) 
        AND (@param2 IS NULL OR (param2  = @param2 ))

  ORDER BY name DESC
  OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @rowsPage) ROWS
  FETCH NEXT @rowsPage ROWS ONLY
```

Linq Code:

```
var result = context.storedProceure(params).Select(s => new object { blah = 
s.blah, blah1 = s.blah1}).ToList();
```

Error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Linq can figure out the complex result type if I remove the Offset Next Command.

How can I help the entity framework figure out the result type?

I've tried:

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET FMTONLY OFF;

neither seem to make a difference...

Comment: I think you need to set `@pageNumber = 1`. Because the calculation `((@pageNumber - 1) * @rowsPage)` returns -10. Which I don't think you can skip -10 rows.

Comment: Well, I was hoping it would be that simple.  It is still giving the same error.  I'm wondering if I could nest the entire query inside a select that returns the same fields....just to force the entity framework to find the return type.  I'm worried about performance with this though...

Comment: Not that this will make a difference (I don't think), but you reference `@param1` only in the `Where` clause. I think you want `@param2` in there on the second line.

Comment: Ahh, yea.  That was clumsy typing for the sake of the question.  I'll edit that.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything online that suggests anyone else has experience the same issue.  Seem fairly generic...  It's driving me nuts.  Everything seems to point to temporary tables...

Comment: I was going to suggest inserting into temp table then return those results, but that does seem arbitrary.